# Elastic search - Kafka Connect not publishing correct value of key as document id

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to publish data from kafka topic to Elastic search using Kafka connect. 
Below is my configuration.

```js
{
  "name": "elasticsearch_sink_19",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "k-connect-status",
    "connection.url": "http://docker.for.mac.host.internal:9200",
    "type.name": "connectstatus",
    "behavior.on.malformed.documents": "ignore",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter", 
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "validate.non.null": "false",
    "key.ignore":"true",
    "schema.ignore":"true",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
  }
}
```

"key.ignore" true is publishing data with wrong _id (not expected _id).

**Data from topic:**

Format:JSON

```js
{
  "ROWTIME":1591743374742,
  "ROWKEY":"status-connector-elasticsearch_sink_31",
  "state":"RUNNING",
  "trace":null,
  "worker_id":"connect:8083",
  "generation":2
}
```

**Sample Elastic Search Output:**

```js
{
  "_index" : "k-connect-status",
  "_type" : "connectstatus",
  "_id" : "k-connect-status+1+17",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "generation" : 11,
    "trace" : null,
    "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
    "worker_id" : "connect:8083"
  }
}
```

**Expected Elastic Search Output**

```js
{
  "_index" : "k-connect-status",
  "_type" : "connectstatus",
  "_id" : "status-connector-elasticsearch_sink_31",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "generation" : 11,
    "trace" : null,
    "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
    "worker_id" : "connect:8083"
  }
}
```

ROWKEY as _id of the elastic search. Atleast ROWKEY appended with topic name.

"key.ignore" false is not publishing any data.

Comment: Why `31` should be in `_id`? What format of `_id` do you want to achieve?

Comment: ROWKEY of the message should be _id on elastic search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"key.ignore":"true",` is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. It ignores the key of the Kafka message, and instead uses the tuple of topic+partition+offset, which is what you can see in your quoted Elasticsearch output:

```
  "_id" : "k-connect-status+1+17",
```

If you want to use the key of the Kafka message you need to set     `"key.ignore":"false"`

Check out this tutorial to learn more and see an explanation of keys [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cq-2eGxOCc8&t=437s) / [code](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/kafka-to-elasticsearch/README.adoc#key-handling)

- Watch it here: https://rmoff.dev/kafka-elasticsearch-video
- Try it here:   https://rmoff.dev/kafka-elasticsearch

Comment: setting "key.ignore":"false" is not publishing any messages to Elastic Search. I don't see any exception. Strange!
is it issue with JSON format Value and Key being String ?

Comment: I would remove  `"errors.tolerance": "all",` and `"behavior.on.malformed.documents": "ignore"` and check the log if that shows any failures. If the key is String, then use the StringConverter. The value part of the message will be irrelevant.

Comment: Problem is with incompatible version of elastic search. Resolved by Downgrading ES to 6.7.2.                                                                 Exception: {"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_version]"}

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch and Kafka Connect ES connector are you using? ES 7.5 with connector v5.5 should work fine

Answer (score 1):

[Elasticsearch Sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html) by default create document _id by concatenating: topic, partitions and offsets. It happens in your situtaion.
You should set `key.ignore` on `false` and deliver proper key.

If you need to extract some information from message value and put it in key, you  should use proper [Transformation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/index.html). I think you can try with [ValueToKey](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/valuetokey.html#valuetokey).